# Triggering infinite loop in ember routing mechanism

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/EJQ8v/

Click to the post, and then to comments. Am I doing something wrong? This type of case shows up multiple times in my app, and I'm not sure how to have it arrive at this route successfully.

Edit: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1231 this issue & fix doesn't seem related, but perhaps it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This seems to work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/NZYxC/4/)

Overall your routing seems really complicated to me and possibly doing things wrong. Maybe you're trying to do something more complex and my simplification of it has wrecked it?

```
    posts: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/posts',
        gotoPost: Em.Route.transitionTo('post'),

        connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('posts', App.Post.find());
        },

        post: Em.Route.extend({
            route: '/posts/:post_id',
            gotoComments: Em.Route.transitionTo('post.comments'),

            connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('post', post);
            },

            comments: Em.Route.extend({
                route: '/posts/:post_id/comments',
                connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
                   router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('comments', post);
                },

            }),
        })
    }),
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that only leaf routes should be navigable, and that routes are relative. (Your fiddle doesn't appear to be in sync with the code? The jsfiddle is the same one I sent, I believe, and I get a "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in the log.)

Comment: See the URLs this generates in the status bar -- the routes are relative. I can't seem to emulate this code without an error: http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/#toc_nesting -- I believe I can just put comments on the same level as post, and set route = '/:post_id/comments', but I can't understand why it isn't working otherwise

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I went with, and your first answer helped me get there. But I'm still confused as to why the post.comments subroute didn't work at all, hopefully someone can clarify

Comment: I found this question because I'm having a similar problem. It looks like this one got solved, but I can't tell from three jsFiddles and these comments what, exactly, solved it. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Instead of nesting the static route inside the dynamic route, make it a sibling, and include the dynamic portion in the route property: `route: '/:dynamic/static'`. Still don't know why it doesn't work the original way.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I see... that doesn't help me, then, because I'm seeing this error in a state which has a static path and is a child of `root`.